# Как выводить другое изображение в окне tk при передвижении шкалы

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня имеется следующий код:

```
#блок библиотек
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

#блок создания окна
window = Tk()
window.geometry('1920x1080')

#блок условия шкалы
def on_scroll(fst):
    a=fst

#блок создания шкалы
scale =Scale(window, from_=1, to=3, command=on_scroll, orient=HORIZONTAL)
scale_var = tk.IntVar()
scale.pack()

#блок изображения
a=1
img = Image.open(r'D:\mt\75\%d.1.png' % (a))
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
initil = Label(window, image=render).place(x=0, y=65) #нормальные координаты
window.mainloop()
```

Мне нужно поменять изображение на другое, когда двигается бегунок шкалы. Но сейчас изображение остаётся прежним. Как исправить проблему, желательно без установок и подключения дополнительных библиотек.

Answer (score 0):

*Для начала хотел бы дать совет, использeйте ООП стиль*

*Это очень удобно меньше путаницы в коде*

**Ну а теперь главное я сам не понял почему так работает**

```
self.label["image"] = self.lion_image
```

**А так нет self.label.image = self.lion_image**

*Надеюсь кто нибудь из Гуру пояснит)*

*Ну и код собственно:*

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Scale, Canvas, mainloop, VERTICAL
import sys
from io import BytesIO
from threading import Thread
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import requests


def thread(target):
    def wrapper(*args):
        th = Thread(target=target, args=args)
        th.start()
    return wrapper


class ScrollingImage(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resulting_image()
        self.interface()

    def interface(self):
        self.geometry('1300x700')

        self.title("Большие кошки")

        self.label = Label(self, bg="gray55", text="Loading...", width=140, height=40)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.scale = Scale(self, command=self.scrolling, from_=1, to=3)
        self.scale.config(length=650, width=50, sliderlength=100)
        self.scale.grid(row=0, column=1)

    @thread
    def resulting_image(self):
        one_image = requests.get("https://st.depositphotos.com/2977105/3691/i/950/depositphotos_36916547-stock-photo-tiger-portrait-horizontal.jpg").content
        two_image =  requests.get("https://st.depositphotos.com/1004061/3547/i/950/depositphotos_35477449-stock-photo-big-lion-lying-on-savannah.jpg").content

        print("Загрузка завершена...")

        one = BytesIO(one_image)
        two = BytesIO(two_image)

        self.tiger = Image.open(one)
        self.lion = Image.open(two)


    def scrolling(self, event):
        self.tiger_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.tiger, master=self)
        self.lion_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.lion, master=self)
        if event == "1":
            self.label["image"] = self.tiger_image
            self.label.config(width=1000, height=550)
        elif event == "2":
           self.label["image"] = self.lion_image
           self.label.config(width=1000, height=550)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ScrollingImage()
    app.mainloop()
```